# compile error on variadic template function parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces, variadic-templates, compiler-bug

I'm trying to write some parameter wrapping helper code like below

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

struct test{};

namespace ns {
    struct test{};
}

template<typename T>
struct arg_wrapper;

template<>
struct arg_wrapper<test>
{
    arg_wrapper(test&) {}
};

template<>
struct arg_wrapper<ns::test>
{
    arg_wrapper(ns::test&) {}
};

template<>
struct arg_wrapper<std::string>
{
    arg_wrapper(const std::string& value) {}
};

template<typename... Args>
void callee(const Args&... args)
{
}

template<typename... Args>
void wrapper_variadic(Args&&... args)
{
    callee(arg_wrapper<typename std::decay<Args>::type>(args)...);
}

template<typename Args>
void wrapper_fixed(Args&& args)
{
    callee(arg_wrapper<typename std::decay<Args>::type>(args));
}

int main()
{
    std::string a("test");
    wrapper_variadic(a); // works well
    wrapper_variadic(std::string("test")); // compile error
    wrapper_variadic(test()); // works well
    wrapper_variadic(ns::test()); // compile error
    wrapper_fixed(std::string("test")); // works well
    wrapper_fixed(test()); // works well
    wrapper_fixed(ns::test()); // works well
}
```

This code works on fixed parameter function or l-value ref of type without namespace, but my compiler rejects attempt to use r-value ref parameter with some namespace. I'm using vc11 ctp version, and the error message is somewhat incomprehensible (see below)

```
1>d:\work\toy\vs2012test\vs2012test\source.cpp(39): error C2065: 'basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >' : undeclared identifier
1>          d:\work\toy\vs2012test\vs2012test\source.cpp(52) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void wrapper_variadic<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>>(std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &&)' being compiled
1>d:\work\toy\vs2012test\vs2012test\source.cpp(39): error C2923: 'std::decay' : 'basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'
1>d:\work\toy\vs2012test\vs2012test\source.cpp(39): error C2955: 'std::decay' : use of class template requires template argument list
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\type_traits(1620) : see declaration of 'std::decay'
1>d:\work\toy\vs2012test\vs2012test\source.cpp(39): error C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' to 'arg_wrapper<_If<std::is_array<remove_reference<_Ty>::type>::value,remove_extent<remove_reference<_Ty>::type>::type*,_If<std::is_function<remove_reference<_Ty>::type>::value,add_pointer<remove_reference<_Ty>::type>::type,remove_cv<remove_reference<_Ty>::type>::type>::type>::type>'
1>          Source or target has incomplete type
1>d:\work\toy\vs2012test\vs2012test\source.cpp(39): error C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'ns::test' to 'arg_wrapper<test>'
1>          No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
1>          d:\work\toy\vs2012test\vs2012test\source.cpp(54) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void wrapper_variadic<ns::test>(ns::test &&)' being compiled
```

It looks like a compiler bug, but I don't have confidence for that. Is this bug? If not, then what should I do to fix the problem?

Comment: Definitely looks like an error. Bravo for the test case ;)

Comment: VC has finally implemented variadic templates?

Comment: The CTP variadics are buggy as hell. I tried to port code from GCC/Clang, which uses variadics in a number of ways, and filed 11 variadic bugs that night (+3 for `decltype`). :)

Comment: The code compiles under g++ 4.7.1

Comment: @Xeo : Can you post links to the bug reports somewhere so we can upvote them please?

Comment: @ildjarn: Sorry, can't. :/ I filed them via STL, who filed them on their internal bug tracker.

Comment: @Xeo : Ah, fair enough. Probably more effective that way than via Connect. ;-]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It compiles fine with g++ 4.7.2 and clang++ 3.2. It is probably a compiler bug. It seems that vc11 doesn't implement expanding packs properly.